# Side effects of global-set-key?

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, compilation

I have had `(global-set-key [f9] 'compile)` in my Emacs init file for many years.  With this setup, hitting `[f9]` and doing `M-x compile RET` should run the same commands the same way, right?

But today I was having trouble with a Bash script.  I ran it, as usual, by hitting `[f9]`, but got a mysterious error.  After several vain attempts to find a bug in my script, I suddenly discovered that when I execute it with `M-x compile` instead, it succeeds, and that it also succeeds when run on a VT or gnome-terminal.  So it turns out — to my big surprise — that running `compile` via a shortcut key or via `M-x` do not always do the same thing.

(
Minimal working example (saved as `/tmp/ledger-test`; the `drewr3.dat` file was copied from [Ledger's GIT source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ledger/ledger/master/test/input/drewr3.dat)):

```
#! /bin/bash
ledgerfile=/tmp/drewr3.dat
# run ledger under env -i, to leave no room for possible differences in environment:
env -i TERM=ansi ledger --no-color -f $ledgerfile balance
```

When I set `compile-command` to `"bash /tmp/ledger-test"` and run the script via `M-x compile`, it runs normally.  But when I run it by hitting `[f9]` , it fails:

```
While evaluating value expression:
  ansify_if(justify(scrub(display_total), 20, (20 + int(prepend_width)), true, color), (should_bold ? (bold : null)))
While calling function 'int ':
While calling function 'justify ($ -3,804.00, <#EXPR {20}>, <#EXPR ({20} + int(prepend_width))>, 1, 0)':
While calling function 'ansify_if (<#EXPR justify(scrub(display_total), {20}, ({20} + int(prepend_width)), true, color)>, )':
Error: bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

)

What's going on, and how to make `[f9]` work identically with `M-x compile`?

I am running Emacs 28.1 on Arch Linux.  (Running Emacs with `-Q` does not help.)

P.S.  I tried to work around the trouble by creating a keyboard macro that runs `compile`, and binding it to `[f9]`:

```
M-x global-unset-key RET [f9]
C-x ( M-x compile RET C-x ) 
M-x name-last-keyboard-macro RET my-compile RET
M-x global-set-key RET [f9] my-compile RET
```

But this did not help: when I hit `[f9]` now, I get the same error again.

Comment: What does `C-h k <f9>` in that buffer report?

Comment: @phils First line: "<f9> runs the command compile (found in global-map), which is an
autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘compile.el’."  This is followed by bindings for compile (including <f9>), signature of the compile function and its docstring.

Comment: Ok; that was my one and only idea (that `<f9>` unexpectedly had a different binding).  I also think it should be the same as `M-x compile` in this case.  That the method of invocation would somehow vary the *outcome* of running the script is bizarre, but I would suggest you focus on debugging the script failure as a way to glean some insight into what the actual difference was, and then see if you can relate that back to Emacs somehow.

Comment: I can't reproduce it: I bound `compile` to `C-c z` - `<f9>` is in use already in my case - and do `M-x compile RET bash /tmp/foo.sh` and `C-c z RET` which has the `bash /tmp/foo.sh` command defaulted. I get identical output in both cases: a `*compilation*` buffer with more or less the same output as executing the script from the command line (more or less because the `TERM=ansi` setting makes `ledger` produce ansi escape codes in the output which are not interpreted when sent to the `*compilation*` buffer). Setting `compile-command` to `bash /tmp/foo.sh` works in exactly the same way.